# VirtualWire - Send Integer Array

Tags: arduino, radio-transmission

how can I send and receive array of integers in Arduino using VirtualLibrary. I declared array like this:

```
int toSend[] = {1,4,5,7,9};
```

How to correctly send and receive it? Maybe someone can help me?

Comment: can you show us some documentation and be a little more explicit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop over the array `toSend` and call [`Serial.write()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/write) for each element.  Receiving is the reverse (iterate over another array calling [`Serial.read()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/read))